# Read ints from .txt file without reading commas in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read from a text file in C and I just want to read in the integer values into two arrays. Each line has two ints separated by a comma. The first value needs to go in one array and the other needs to go in a different array. Below is an example of the text file and I have also included what I need the two arrays to have. Any help would be appreciated.

Input:

```
 0,5
 0,10
 3,15
 3,5
 7,20
 8,6
 11,9
 14,12
 20,5
 24,7

 one = {0,0,3,3,7,8,11,14,20,24}
 two = {5,10,15,5,20,6,9,12,5,7}
```

UPDATED:

```
    int num;
    fscanf(file_input, "%d", &num);
    printf("%d\n", num);
    int* process[num];
    int* burst[num];
    int* arrival[num];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        process[i] = i + 1;
        fscanf(file_input, "%ls", &arrival[i]);
        //printf("%ls\n", &arrival[i]);
        fscanf(file_input, "%ls", &burst[i]);
        //printf("%ls\n", &burst[i]);
    }       
    printf("%d\n", arrival[2]);
```

Above is what I have tried, but it isn't getting the correct data.

Comment: `while( fscanf(file_input, "%d,%d", arrival + i, burst + i) == 2 ) { ... }`

Comment: I'm extremely confused by this question. The sample input has paired numbers but the loop has a single number read above it.

Comment: So I should read them in together? @Joshua